# Post request is not responding

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, nsurlsession

I'm doing a very simple postRequest but I the service is not responding me, do you have any idea of why this is happening? maybe I'm doing something wrong could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code [Request in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKscf.png)

```
@IBAction func buton(_ sender: Any) {
        let parameters = ["acceptPrivacyNotice": true, "name" :"xxxxx xxxxx", "email": "xxxxx@mail.com", "password":"Qwerty2012", "passwordConfirm":"Qwerty2012","deviceID" : "", "isProvider" : false, "idTypeProvider": 1] as [String : Any]

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.apps-sellcom-dev.com/Engie/api/account/register") else {return}
        var  request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("M1o2K1RVMzRHVSNteUtLOjNzSCR5LUEyKk5qOEhFRg==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        guard  let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {
            return
        }
        request.httpBody = httpBody

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print("Response",response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Dont use `JSONSerialization`, maybe your server doesnt handle that format, try with normal body string first eg.`key=value&...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func buton(_ sender: Any){
    let params = ["acceptPrivacyNotice": true, "name" :"xxxxx xxxxx", "email": "xxxxx@mail.com", "password":"Qwerty2012", "passwordConfirm":"Qwerty2012","deviceID" : "", "isProvider" : false, "idTypeProvider": 1] as [String : Any]
        let session = Foundation.URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apps-sellcom-dev.com/Engie/api/account/register")
        var request = URLRequest(url : url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        do {

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
            request.addValue("M1o2K1RVMzRHVSNteUtLOjNzSCR5LUEyKk5qOEhFRg==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

                    guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                        return
                    }

                    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                    }

                    let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

                    if let responsedata = responseString!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as? Data{

                        do {

                            let jsonResult:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responsedata, options: []) as! NSDictionary
                            print("Get The Result \(jsonResult)")
                            if error != nil {
                                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")

                            }


                            if let str = jsonResult["success"] as? NSNull {
                                print("error=\(str)")

                            }
                            else {
                                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                                print("Response string : \(String(describing: responseString))")
                            }



                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) .resume()
        }catch {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and the reason you are not seeing a response is that the completion block doesn't do anything in case of failure.

When I ran your request, it came back with the following error

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x608000092200 [0x101840c70]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb34bface50000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

My best guess is that there is something wrong in the httpBody. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok , thanks a lot I'll keep checking that I think it's because the "deviceId" parameter in postman should be Null and I don't have experience handling that data types.